# Very strange error while crawling

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml, python-requests, lxml.html

i'm no noob at crawling web pages. But when I started scraping this url
[bse insider trading](http://www.bseindia.com/corporates/Insider_Trading.aspx?expandable=0)

i'm getting a very strange error.

Little details about this page. This Page belongs to one major exchange for indian markets. By default when this page loads, it shows the recent insider trading info. When we select dates and submit, a post request is made and data is displayed. Of course, the data is spanned across several pages.

When I send appropriate post data with custom dates, I'm getting status code `500` for `page$2` which implies I want info on page 2, and all the rest of pages are returning fine. I tried to urlencode this post variable and tried random stuff but with no luck. Please can somebody confirm if this case with you too.

I'm using python, requests, lxml for scraping and here's my code

```
import requests
from lxml import html
import urllib

url = "http://www.bseindia.com/corporates/Insider_Trading.aspx?expandable=0"
data = {'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GetQuote1$smartSearch':'Enter Scrip Name / Code / ID','ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GetQuote1$hdnCode':'','WINDOW_NAMER':'1','__EVENTTARGET':'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvData','__EVENTARGUMENT':'Page$2', 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$fmdate':'20140923', 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$eddate':'20140929', 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtDate':'01/01/2014', 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtTodate':'29/09/2014', 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GetQuote1$hdnCode':'', 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlregulation':'ALL', '__VIEWSTATE':'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', '__EVENTVALIDATION':'/wEWGQLoxuedDgKJsYefCgK6rpDlDwL8np6XAwLl44LQAgK0w8TlCwKHlNXODQKW0sv1BgLei4rQAwKExL/8BQLJsJHgCQLhsb3hCQLJsLmaCAL40JWiCgK9vIn8DAKN+qTQCAKN+qzQCAKN+rjQCAKN+rTQCAKN+qDQCAKN+rzQCAKN+ojQCAKN+oTQCALj8ODgCQKI2cKdDA=='}
cookies = {'_gat':'1', 'expandable':'0c', '_asc':'099bb6b2148be3ebcdb9a1f31af', '__auc':'70dfa206148b7750a132dbe342b', '_ga':'GA1.2.35458869.1411827174'}

headers = {'Referer':'http://www.bseindia.com/corporates/Insider_Trading.aspx?expandable=0', 'Orgin':'http://www.bseindia.com', 'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36'}

for i in range(1,10):
    data['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = ('Page$'+str(i))
    print data['__EVENTARGUMENT'] 
    r = requests.post(url, data=data, cookies=cookies );
    if r.status_code != 200:
        print r.reason
        print i
    root = html.fromstring(r.text)
    a = root.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvData"]/tr')
    for b in a[2:-1]:
        #print b.findall('td')[1].text_content()
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding request parameters, parse it from the page, then follow the pagination:

```
import re

from lxml import html
import requests


def get_data(tree):
    for row in tree.xpath('//tr[@class="TTRow"]/td[1]'):
        print row.text


url = "http://www.bseindia.com/corporates/Insider_Trading.aspx?expandable=0"
headers = {'Referer': 'http://www.bseindia.com/corporates/Insider_Trading.aspx?expandable=0',
           'Origin': 'http://www.bseindia.com',
           'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36',
           'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'}


# start session
session = requests.Session()

# get the main page
response = session.get('http://www.bseindia.com/corporates/Insider_Trading.aspx?expandable=0', headers=headers)
root = html.fromstring(response.content)

# since this is the first page - parse the data 
print "PAGE 1"
get_data(root)
print "------"

data = {
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GetQuote1$smartSearch': 'Enter Scrip Name / Code / ID',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$fmdate': '20140923',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$eddate': '20140929',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtDate': '',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtTodate': '',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GetQuote1$hdnCode': '',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlregulation': 'ALL',

    'myDestination': '#',
    'WINDOW_NAMER': '1',

    '__VIEWSTATE': root.find('.//input[@id="__VIEWSTATE"]').attrib['value'],
    '__EVENTVALIDATION': root.find('.//input[@id="__EVENTVALIDATION"]').attrib['value']
}

pattern = re.compile("javascript:__doPostBack\('(.*?)','(.*?)'\)")
for index, row in enumerate(root.xpath('//tr[@class="pgr"]//td/a'), start=2):
    print "PAGE %d" % index

    target, argument = pattern.search(row.attrib['href']).groups()
    data['__EVENTTARGET'] = target
    data['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = argument

    response = session.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
    root = html.fromstring(response.content)
    get_data(root)
    print "------"
```

Prints (the first column contents in each page):

```
PAGE 1
531807
532706
532959
531807
532840
533400
536507
533400
533304
506395
506395
507717
507717
506395
506395
506395
506395
531807
512393
532268
532466
532689
532689
532706
532706
------
PAGE 2
500228
500246
508969
508969
531802
532532
532532
532832
532832
500228
508969
508969
531802
500124
500124
511243
512393
512393
512393
512393
512393
512393
512393
512393
512393
------
PAGE 3
512393
512393
532466
532508
532799
532799
532799
532799
532799
532799
532799
532799
502355
502355
502355
501700
501700
500247
500247
500875
506615
500247
500875
500875
500875
------
PAGE 4
523838
523838
500875
511503
511503
511503
506615
506615
506615
506615
506615
506615
506615
506615
506615
506615
511503
511503
511503
506395
506395
524348
506685
506685
506685
------
PAGE 5
506685
------
```

Comment: Where are you setting 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtDate' ?

Comment: @Napster sure, I've put a bit of an effort into it. I've tried several things, but right since I've started to get `__*` parameters from the page, the issue was resolved - got 200 for all pages.

Comment: @Napster this is because in browser developer tools I've seen `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtDate` being set to an empty string. I think you can change it to whatever you think is correct here.

Comment: @Napster did the answer help to solve the issue? Is there anything I should add to the answer? Thanks.

Comment: no, i'm still getting 500 with this code if you select from date and to date

Comment: @Napster not sure how do u use the provided code - which parameters do u use? I'm running the exact code and it works for me. Thanks.